# Java jersey validation

Tags: java, validation, jersey

I'm using the validation in Java Jersey, and i'm building an application where it should be possible to save a draft of something. But before it is published, i would like it to be valid, using the annotations in the view model. When publishing, the same savemethod, for draft, is invoked. Therefor i cannot use the annotation in the method (methodName(@Valid ViewmodelName)). Can i somehow invoke a method to validate the annotations in the viewModel? Something like model->isValid(). Alternatively i could make two viewmodels; one for draft and one for published, but seems kind of double work.

Best regards

Comment: How do you determine if something is a draft?

Comment: I am not sure I am reading your question right... are you asking for a way to invoke standard validation on your annotated model programmatically?

Comment: Thank you both for your replies!
Yeah, i'm asking for a way of invoking the standard validation programmatically! :)
I determine if it is a draft because then they press "save" instead of publish, which result in two different methods. But when you press publish, behind the scenes the save method is invoked and after that the status of the object is just change to "published" - given that it is valid. 
regards

Comment: @anders  If you don't tag me in your comment, I don't get a notification that you commented

Comment: @pandaadb Will do in the future! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so from your comment I think what you want is to manually validate your annotated bean. This is fairly easy. What you need to do is:

- Create a Validator implementation (my example uses hibernate validation)
- Call validate on it and check the results

I created a small sample that illustrates that:

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    public class HibernaterTest {



        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

            MyModel m = new MyModel();
            m.test = null;

            Set<ConstraintViolation<MyModel>> validate = validator.validate(m);
            System.err.println(validate.size());

            m.test = "some string";

            validate = validator.validate(m);
            System.err.println(validate.size());
        }


        public static class MyModel {

            @NotNull
            String test;

        }
    }
```

The first validation call will print 1, while the second will print 0. This is because the model's test property originally is null.

I hope this answers your question,

Artur

Comment: Exacly! Thank you very much!